# Database Locked Error in my code

Tags: ios, sqlite

Getting Database Locked error while executing this,Pls refer thhis code

```
sqlite3 *database;
NSString * databaseName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:DBName];
NSArray * documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] retain];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int customer_id = [[defaults objectForKey:@"cus_id"] intValue];

BOOL check=[self isContainsJwelIDForOrderGem:@"orderjewelprice_gram" idval:jid user_id:customer_id];
if(!check)
    {
    NSString *lite=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into orderjewelprice_gram (id, metal_type, classification, gram, price, total_price, wastage, making, cost_price, jID, user_id) select * from jewelprice_gram where jID = %d",jid];
    if(Debug)
        DLog(@"Insert sqlQuery::%@",lite);

    const char *sqlStatement = [lite UTF8String];

        // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement=nil;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
            if(Debug)
                {
                DLog(@"not Insert");
                DLog(@"HMM, COULDNT RUN QUERY: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }
            }
        else
            {
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    //if(Debug)
                    DLog(@"Inserted successfully");
                }
            }
        NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    }
int user_id;
BOOL isCheck = [self isContainsJwelIDForOrderGem:@"orderjewelprice_gram" idval:jid user_id:0];
if(isCheck)
    user_id = 0;
else
    user_id = customer_id;
NSString *lite1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE orderjewelprice_gram SET wastage ='%@',making = '%@', price = '%@',user_id = %d where jID = %d and user_id = %d",wastage,making,price,customer_id,jid,user_id];
    //if(Debug)
    DLog(@"update sqlQuery::%@",lite1);

const char *sqlStatement1 = [lite1 UTF8String];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement=nil;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement1, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
        if(Debug)
            {
            DLog(@"not updated");
            DLog(@"HMM, COULDNT RUN QUERY: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
        }
    else
        {
        if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                //if(Debug)
                DLog(@"updated successfully");
            }
        }
    NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
sqlite3_close(database);
[databaseName release];
[databasePath release];
```

Comment: Not related to Xcode. Also, formatting & indentation!

Comment: You need to decouple your database open/close from the operations on the database.  It's expensive to keep opening the database whenever you want to do something.  Have some sort of lazy-open semantic and only close it when you get an app-delegate "go to sleep" notification.

Comment: Testing in Device Or Simulator?

Comment: I tested in simulator @KumarKl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database close correctly or your database already opened so that database locked